# Conditional joint probabiltiy P(A|BCDEF) from single conditional P(A|B), P(A|C), etc?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have a matrix of conditional single probabilities, e.g.:
P(A|D), P(A|E)...P(C|H); also, P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1.

How would I express a joint conditional probability, say P(A|DEFGH), if DEFGH are all independent events?

Via research I've seen many very helpful examples of Bayes' rule using 2 variables (A,D), e.g. P(A|D) = P(AD)/P(D), but am not sure how to generalize to multiple conditions?

```
P(A) = 0.0733, P(B) = 0.2099, P(C) = 0.7169 

      A      B       C
D [0.7436 0.1302 0.0081]
E [0.8757 0.4916 0.0759]
F [0.8764 0.2907 0.0041]
G [0.5940 0.3245 0.0134]
H [0.9959 0.7803 0.2625]
```

Comment: The marginal probabilities of $A,B,C$ may add up to $1$ but the conditional probabilities appear not to. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Yes, this is deliberate - it's the output from a script I'm familiarizing myself with.

Answer (score 1):

Your example $P(A|DEFGH)$.
Using the [multiplication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29)
\begin{align*}
P(ADEFGH) &= P(H)P(ADEFG|H) \\
&= P(H)P(G|H)P(ADEF|GH)\\
&=\dotsb\\
&=P(H)P(G|H)P(F|GH)P(E|FGH)P(D|EFGH)P(A|DEFGH)\\
&=P(H)P(G)P(F)P(E)P(D)P(A|DEFGH)
\end{align*}
where the last line is true because of independence.
Thus
$$P(A|DEFGH) = \frac{P(ADEFGH)}{P(H)P(G)P(F)P(E)P(D)}.$$

Comment: Thanks @probablyme!  But since all I have is matrix of single conditional probabilities [P(A|D), P(A|E)..P(C|H)] and P(A), P(B), and P(C), is there a way to express P(A|DEDFGH) as function of only these elements?

Comment: @pniessen I don't think so> I could be over-looking something thought. It might work if you had probabilities conditioned on $A$.

Comment: Have I made a mistake, @probablyme?  The table contains just that e.g. probabilities, conditional on class membership (A, B, C) that an individual demonstrates an affirmative response to a survey question (D (or E, F, G, H)).  So proper notation would be P(D|A), P(E|A)...P(H|C), right?   Apologies for rookie error!

Comment: Hmm.  That evaluates to (0.0733)(0.7436)(0.8757)(0.8764)(0.5940)(0.9959) / (0.0733)^5 = 13625, which doesn't seem right :-(

Comment: @pniessen Sorry, the previous thing I wrote was a huge typo. I meant to write
$$P(A|DEFGH) = \frac{P(A)P(A|D)P(A|E)P(A|F)P(A|G)P(A|H)}{[P(A)]^5}.$$ But I think you are saying that you don't have these correct?